Force on a charge inside a conductor in presence of external electric field
It is known that electric field inside the conductor in electrostatics is zero. Now, if I a place a charge (let the charge be q) anywhere inside a charged spherical shell (let the charge be Q) which is metallic (conductor), and that too in presence of an external electric field (let it be E) , what would be the net force on it due to all forces? Will it be zero or non-zero? Also, what will be the force on it due to the conductor if external electric field is absent. Will it be zero?
Please explain this in a little more depth. I know that when a charge is placed inside it, to make electric field inside the conductor zero, a equal and opposite charge is induced in the inner part of the conductor and outer part of conductor. After this will the net force be zero? Please analyse and answer. Any help will be appreciated.
